# How to solve "NaN-NaN-0NaN" error while converting indian format using JsSimpleDateFormat?

Tags: javascript, date

When I am using javascript date to convert from its default format to Indian format it shows 'Invalid Date' error.

The format is as follows:

```
var indDate=new JsSimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

When using the following format,

```
indDate.format(new Date("12-09-2014")) //convert correctly as "09-12-2014"
```

But when using this one,

```
indDate.format(new Date("13-09-2014")) //shows "NaN-NaN-0NaN"
```

Up to date value 12 is working correctly. But after that (from 13) not working properly.

How to solve that. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Nothing to solve actually. Date function is waiting for a valid entrance which a month value can be up to max 12.

Comment: But I used indian format "dd-MM-yyyy" . so should it accept first value as date?

Comment: @BabuR could you please update your question to indicate that this `JsSimpleDateFormat` is part of some library (not part of JavaScript)?

Comment: It is gonna format the date as "dd-MM-yyyy" but before that, `Date() `function is waiting for a valid entrance to produce a date.

Comment: Oooooh why do countries use insane non-lexically sortable date formats! :-) YYYY-MM-DD forever!!!!! (oops, edit)

Comment: or at least until 10000AD. :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the date object then this will work:

```
    var year = 2014, month = 9, day = 13;
    var date = new Date(year, month - 1, day);  // month is zero based
    console.log(date); // prints: Sat Sep 13 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Eastern Europe Daylight Time)
```

I dont have a reference to "JsSimpleDateFormat" so I dont really know what it does.